# Is there an ADB command to delete contact using number in phone?

Tags: command, adb, contacts

I need to delete saved profile contact using adb command.

Is it possible to delete profile contact using its number?

Answer (score 0):

you can try
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.DELETE -t vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact -e name 'Contact Name' -e phone 72xxxxxxxx

but adb shell pm clear com.android.providers.contacts  will clear all contacts from a contact list.